# What does this server ssh response mean?

Tags: ssh

I attempted to pown my first lab box and I got the following response from the server after providing correct user/pwd for ssh login.

> no matching key exchange method found. Their offer:
>   gss-group1-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

What is this response and do I provide the correct method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenSSH implements all of the cryptographic algorithms needed for compatibility with standards-compliant SSH implementations, but since some of the older algorithms have been found to be weak, not all of them are enabled by default. This page describes what to do when OpenSSH refuses to connect with an implementation that only supports legacy algorithms.
I found my answer to my question:

When a SSH client connects to a server, each side offers lists of connection parameters to the other. These are, with the corresponding ssh_config keyword:

```
KexAlgorithms: the key exchange methods that are used to generate per-connection keys
Ciphers: the ciphers to encrypt the connection
MACs: the message authentication codes used to detect traffic modification
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes: the public key algorithms that the server can use to authenticate itself to the client
```

ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 user@legacyhost